# Splitting an Ico Sphere into chunks

Tags: mesh

I'm making a planet for my game using an Ico Sphere with a large number of subdivisions.
To be able to load and run it in Unity, I need to split it into more or less equal chunks (max. 65,534 verts).
Doing it by hand is obviously not an option.
Any idea how to do this without scripting?

Comment: You could use something like an *Edge Split* modifier to split all edges then *Separate by Loose Parts*

Comment: Won't it separate all individual faces?

Comment: You can mark desired edges as Sharp beforehand, or adjust the angle threshold